# Is there a way to keep querying with request futures until complete?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using the `requests-futures` library. One could basically loop through and query like so:

```
from concurrent.futures import as_completed
from pprint import pprint
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession

session = FuturesSession()

futures=[session.get(f'http://httpbin.org/get?{i}') for i in range(3)]

for future in as_completed(futures):
    resp = future.result()
    pprint({
        'url': resp.request.url,
        'content': resp.json(),
    })
```

However, this is if range is defined. My problem is my range is not defined and I'd like to get all pages basically until the loop hits a deadend. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you don't know the range, maybe you can let it run in a while loop adding values and break it when you hit different status code than 200?

Comment: @Leemosh Would the while loop work with this library though?

Comment: @Leemosh The loop would collect future promises, so that wouldn't work...